# A Slurm job can't request GPUs resources for more than one node

Tags: linux, gpu, slurm, sbatch

all.

In my Slurm cluster, when a srun or sbatch job requests resources more than one node, it will not be submitted correctly.

This Slurm cluster has 4 nodes, each node has 4 GPUs.

I can execute multiple jobs with 4 GPUs at the same time.

But I can't run a job request 5 GPUs or more.

The following message will show that the cise3 status is down, this is another problem.

## error message：

sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available

## start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -o code20.out
#SBATCH --partition=cup-hpc
#SBATCH --nodes=3
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=40
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:5
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=100mb

source /home/slurm/tensorflow_prj/tf_gpu_cluster/bin/activate
python3 /nfs/code/code20.py
```

## slurm.conf:

```
NodeName=cise1 NodeAddr=10.18.19.191 CPUs=40 RealMemory=94887 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=10 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN Gres=gpu:rtx4000:4
NodeName=cise2 NodeAddr=10.18.19.107 CPUs=40 RealMemory=94889 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=10 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN Gres=gpu:rtx4000:4
NodeName=cise3 NodeAddr=10.18.19.47  CPUs=40 RealMemory=94889 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=10 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN Gres=gpu:rtx4000:4
NodeName=cise4 NodeAddr=10.18.19.183 CPUs=40 RealMemory=94889 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=10 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN Gres=gpu:rtx4000:4
PartitionName=cup-hpc Nodes=cise[1-4] Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

## gres.conf:

```
# Configure support for four GPUs (with MPS), plus bandwidth
AutoDetect=nvml
Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia0
Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia1
Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia2
Name=gpu File=/dev/nvidia3
```

## sinfo:

```
[root@localhost nfs]# sinfo
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
cup-hpc*     up   infinite      1  down* cise3
cup-hpc*     up   infinite      3   idle cise[1-2,4]
```

## scontrol show nodes:

```
[root@localhost nfs]# scontrol show nodes
NodeName=cise1 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=10
   CPUAlloc=0 CPUTot=40 CPULoad=0.01
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=gpu:rtx4000:4
   NodeAddr=10.18.19.191 NodeHostName=cise1 Version=20.02.1
   OS=Linux 4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 4 09:19:46 UTC 2019
   RealMemory=94887 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=83727 Sockets=2 Boards=1
   State=IDLE ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=cup-hpc
   BootTime=2020-04-13T08:34:13 SlurmdStartTime=2020-04-17T14:49:20
   CfgTRES=cpu=40,mem=94887M,billing=40
   AllocTRES=
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 AveWatts=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s


NodeName=cise2 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=10
   CPUAlloc=0 CPUTot=40 CPULoad=0.00
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=gpu:rtx4000:4
   NodeAddr=10.18.19.107 NodeHostName=cise2 Version=20.02.1
   OS=Linux 4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 4 09:19:46 UTC 2019
   RealMemory=94889 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=83405 Sockets=2 Boards=1
   State=IDLE ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=cup-hpc
   BootTime=2020-04-13T08:33:51 SlurmdStartTime=2020-04-17T14:49:33
   CfgTRES=cpu=40,mem=94889M,billing=40
   AllocTRES=
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 AveWatts=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s


NodeName=cise3 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=10
   CPUAlloc=0 CPUTot=40 CPULoad=0.00
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=gpu:rtx4000:4
   NodeAddr=10.18.19.47 NodeHostName=cise3 Version=20.02.1
   OS=Linux 4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 4 09:19:46 UTC 2019
   RealMemory=94889 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=83456 Sockets=2 Boards=1
   State=DOWN* ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=cup-hpc
   BootTime=2020-04-13T08:31:48 SlurmdStartTime=2020-04-17T15:10:16
   CfgTRES=cpu=40,mem=94889M,billing=40
   AllocTRES=
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 AveWatts=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
   Reason=Not responding [slurm@2020-04-17T15:17:58]

NodeName=cise4 Arch=x86_64 CoresPerSocket=10
   CPUAlloc=0 CPUTot=40 CPULoad=0.00
   AvailableFeatures=(null)
   ActiveFeatures=(null)
   Gres=gpu:rtx4000:4
   NodeAddr=10.18.19.183 NodeHostName=cise4 Version=20.02.1
   OS=Linux 4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 4 09:19:46 UTC 2019
   RealMemory=94889 AllocMem=0 FreeMem=83432 Sockets=2 Boards=1
   State=IDLE ThreadsPerCore=2 TmpDisk=0 Weight=1 Owner=N/A MCS_label=N/A
   Partitions=cup-hpc
   BootTime=2020-04-13T08:36:40 SlurmdStartTime=2020-04-17T14:49:23
   CfgTRES=cpu=40,mem=94889M,billing=40
   AllocTRES=
   CapWatts=n/a
   CurrentWatts=0 AveWatts=0
   ExtSensorsJoules=n/s ExtSensorsWatts=0 ExtSensorsTemp=n/s
```

Comment: what is the value shown by `scontrol show config | grep ^SelectType` ?

Comment: SelectType              = select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters    = CR_CORE

Comment: ok then run the `scontrol show nodes` command again but while the four jobs are running and look at `allocTRES` , `CPUAlloc`. What are they?

Comment: I changed #SBATCH --nodes=1 and submitted three same tasks because one of the nodes is down. cise[1-2,4] these three nodes show CPUAlloc=40 and 
AllocTRES=cpu=40. These three tasks are run on three different node.

Comment: Then you are consuming all 40 CPUs of each nodes with the three jobs, and the fourth one cannot start event if some GPUs are available.

Comment: Even if I only run one task, I still cannot use more than four idle GPUs

Comment: if you remove `#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=40` ?

Comment: Yes, even if I remove #SBATCH --cpus-per-task=40 or change it to =4, I still cannot run the job with more than four GPUs

Comment: then you will have to look in the `slurmctld` log files increasing the log level `scontrol set debug 3` and adding flag `scheduler` to the DebugFlags

Answer (score 2):

The slurm gres specification is a per node request. Your job is currently requesting 3 nodes with 5 GPUs each.

Source: https://slurm.schedmd.com/gres.html#Running_Jobs